# Oracle query to fix the data

Tags: sql, oracle, null, case

I have a column transaction_value , here is the requirement if the value is empty then i need to replace it with null

i have tried the below case statement

```
CASE WHEN nc.transaction_value WHEN IS NULL
     THEN nc.transaction_value
     ELSE nc.transaction_value
```

END nc.transaction_value

Comment: What do you mean when empty then you need NULL. In Oracle an empty string is NULL. Please post data and desired output clearly. `CASE` is ANSI compliant, so you cannot compare null to null, it means nothing. More Oracle way of doing it is using `DECODE`.

Comment: correction i have the source values 123456 when ia m puiing the source column values i am not getting all the values , i am getting 456 what is the function i need to use ?

Comment: Do not add information in comments. Instead, [edit] the question and include it there where it's available in your post. *when im putting the source column values* is also pretty difficult to understand. When you make your [edit], you might want to consider being more clear about that sentence.